# Testing Angular controller with Require and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript, karma-runner

I am trying to create a basic test to verify that I can create a controller or service.

My app is is the following directory

```
app/js/app.js
```

My controllers are in the following directory

```
app/js/controllers/
```

Here is my karma.conf.js file

```
        files: [
        'Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
        'Scripts/require.js',
        'Scripts/angular.js',
        'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
        { pattern: 'app/js/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'app/js/**/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'app/js/**/**/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'app/js/**/**/**/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'test/specs/**/*.js', included: false },
         'test/test-main.js',
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
         'app/js/main.js'
    ],
```

test-main.js

```
var testFiles = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
console.log(file);
if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
    testFiles.push(file);
}
}

requirejs.config({
paths: {
    // External libraries
    'jquery': '../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min',
    'angular': '../../Scripts/angular',
    'angular-mocks': '../../Scripts/angular-mocks',
    'ngRoute': '../../Scripts/angular-route.min',
    'angular-animate': '../../Scripts/angular-animate.min',
   'angular-cookies': '../../Scripts/angular-cookies.min',

},
baseUrl: '/base/app/js',

shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular',
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'angular-mocks': { exports: 'angular-mocks', deps: ['angular']  },
    'angular-animate': { exports: 'angular-animate', deps: ['angular'] },
    'ngRoute': { exports: 'ngRoute', deps: ['angular'] },
    'angular-cookies': { exports: 'angular-cookies', deps: ['angular'] },
},

  // dynamically load all test files
deps: testFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

I added this line...

```
console.log(file)
```

To make sure the file was loaded into

```
window.__karma__.files
```

and it is.

The test lives in test/specs/

```
define(['angular', 'angular-mocks'], (angular, ngMock: ng.IMockStatic) => {
var module = ngMock.module;
var inject: (...fns: Function[]) => any = ngMock.inject;

describe("Create an Application", function () {
    var scope, q, routeParams;
    var location;
    var app;
    beforeEach(function () {

        app = angular.module('App', []);
        inject(function ($rootScope, $q: ng.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            q = $q;
            routeParams = {};
            location = $location;
        });
    });

    it('Test Application Created', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
});
```

My app file looks like this....

```
import angular = require('angular');
import angularRoute = require('angular-route');
import angularAnimate = require('angular-animate');
import ds = require('services/DataService');

var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'kendo.directives',
    'breeze.angular',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);

export = app;
```

the error that i get when I try to run the test is

failed to instantiate module app due to: Module 'app' is not available!  You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

I am assuming it is not loading but not sure how I can tell.  Is this the best way to accomplish my testing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!

[image: Grunt output]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Karma with Jasmine, you may be having the problem of Jasmine being too eager.

This can be fixed by making two changes, originally described in an article I wrote when I was doing a similar thing, [Combining TypeScript, Jasmine and RequireJS](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201407/Blog/Combining-TypeScript-Jasmine-And-AMD-With-RequireJS/).

In *boot.js* you need to comment out the `env.execute();` method call:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
        currentWindowOnload();
    }
    htmlReporter.initialize();
    //env.execute();
};
```

This is because the `window.onload` event can happen before require.js has loaded everything.

Once you have loaded the modules you need, you can then call:

```
// Hai Jasmine - ready to go!
jasmine.getEnv().execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but in the test-main.js file for require, I have this line

     callback: window.__karma__.start

Does that delay the start of jasmine until require has loaded everything?

Comment: You may still need to comment out `env.execute();` in Jasmine's boot.js file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it gets compiled with  your code and  the `-m amd`  switch

```
    describe("Create an Application", function () {
        var scope, q, routeParams;
        var controller, location;
        var route;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'kendo.directives', 'breeze.angular', 'ui.bootstrap']);
            inject(function ($rootScope, $q, $location) {
                scope = $rootScope;
                q = $q;
                routeParams = {};
                location = $location;
            });
            //   controller = new controller.ApplicationService(q, scope, route, location, _datasvc, _searchsvc);
        });
        it('Test Application Created', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

is not a module, and its synchronous

But. in a module works

```
define(['angular','angular-mocks'],(angular,ngMock:ng.IMockStatic)=>{
    var module = ngMock.module;
    var inject: (...fns: Function[])=>any =  ngMock.inject;

    describe("Create an Application", function () {
        var scope, q, routeParams;
        var  location;
        var app;
        beforeEach(function () {

            app = angular.module('App', []);
            inject(function ($rootScope, $q: ng.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
                scope = $rootScope;
                q = $q;
                routeParams = {};
                location = $location;
            });
        });

        it('Test Application Created', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Or alternatively in a more TypeScripty w/ES6esque  way  :

```
    import ngMock = require('angular-mocks');
    import angular = require('angular');
    var module = ngMock.module;
    var inject: (...fns: Function[])=>any =  ngMock.inject;

    describe("Create an Application", function () {
        var scope, q, routeParams;
        var  location;

        beforeEach(function () {
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            inject(function ($rootScope, $q: ng.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
                scope = $rootScope;
                q = $q;
                routeParams = {};
                location = $location;
            });
        });
        it('Test Application Created', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

check that you are loading angular as in a script tag
'`files:[Scripts/angular.js',...`  , 
that's why you get 
 `WARNING:tried load angular more than once` 
Put it in  a { `pattern: 'Scripts/angular.js', included: false ...],`
you need to work out the  requirejs.confg  until the deps chain  are satisfied. in order.,  and thats one of the reasons why you set  the **shim** config with 
 `'angular-mocks': { exports: 'angular-mocks', deps: ['angular']  },`
 so when requiring angular-mocks angular is required  too , 
 have a look at  [this github repo](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-
 seed), 
  ...And once you have  an instance attached to  angular.module /mock.module  in your spec , check Steve's answer again , 
  If you can't find boot.js , you might be  using jasmine bundled with the Karma adapter. in that case it  should work given you have sorted out the  require test-maiin.js / config /   "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!" /resumeBootstrap story

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think you are pointing me in the right direction but I am still getting an error Cannot read property 'module' of undefined at line 2, which is var module = ngMock.module;

Comment: check that I'm requiring 'angular-mocks' that I configured on my 'test-main.js' , you call it 'angularMocks' , it should export angular.mock

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and change my naming to match yours.  I updated my question with the updates I made.  I also attached the output from grunt.  Thanks again for all your help.  I will be nice to get this working!

Comment: added comments. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have to work on another project for a couple of days so I have to put this down.  I will take a look at the github link and compare that to my project.  I do have one question for you...What is"...fns" I have never seen that before.  Thanks for all your help!  I will keep you posted on my progress over the next week.

Comment: is like c# params ,for example:  countArgs(...xs:X[]) declares function 'countArgs' that takes any number of x as parameters. so it can used as in countArgs(x).  or countArgs(x,y,z) , where x,y and z are type X, the function body can use xs as declared (an array) and it could return xs.lentgth'